# Pulling elements from one array and putting them into another using a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, return

I have an assignment to pull a list of integers from a file, "numbs.txt". These numbers are random 1-200. I then need to separate them into ranges of 25(0-24, 25-49...) and report back how man integers are in each range of numbers. Where I am getting lost is when I am trying to get the list of integers back. I am trying to input them into another array in the hopes that i can then count the integers in the new array. I am just learning about functions and arrays in C++ so any help is appreciated.

invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] is the message i receive when I try to call my function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<fstream>   // open, read, and close files
    

using namespace std;

ifstream grades;
string grade_file = "numbs.txt";
const int SCORE_SIZE = 26;
int scores[SCORE_SIZE];
void getNumbs();
int * score_count(int s_count[]);
//void getNumbs(int scores[], int scoreSize);


int main() {

getNumbs();
cout << "The following array positions are scores below 24 file: " << endl;
int s_count[] = score_count(scores[a]); << invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
return 0;
}


void getNumbs(){
ifstream grades;    // input file variable
string grade_file = "numbs.txt";    // inpute file name variable
cout << "Opening File." << endl;    // update
grades.open(grade_file.c_str());    // opening file
if (grades.is_open()){              // Verifying file is open
    cout << grade_file << " Is Open." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < SCORE_SIZE; i++){    // If file is open iterate through the numbers and enter them into string array
        grades >> scores[i];
        cout << scores[i] << " ";
    }
    }
    else {
    cout << "No file found: " << grade_file << endl;
}

    grades.close(); // Close file
    cout << "\nFile is closed." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
// function to separate the numbers between 0 - 24.

int * score_count(int s_count[]){
for (int a = 0; a < SCORE_SIZE; a++){
    if (scores[a] <= 24){
        cin >> s_count[];
        }
    return s_count[];
}
}
```

Comment: Your life task would be much easier if you used `std::vector<int>` instead of a fixed sized c-style array

Comment: `score_count` expects an array as a parameter. `scores[a]` is a single integer, not an array.

Comment: `cin >> s_count[];` and `return s_count[];` are not valid in c++

Comment: What's `a` in `scores[a]`? I don't see the name `a` declared anywhere visible in `main`

Comment: Side note: Lot of global variables. Note that this does not scale well. As your programs get into the hundreds of lines and multiple files, global variables will doom you to much painful debugging. Get out of the habit while you are still young.

Comment: Future bug: Your program seems to have picked up an extra `}`. from somewhere.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I guess I am confused on how I correctly pass the array to score_count?

Comment: @kwayne -- If you used `std::vector`, the code becomes very simple.  You should have focused on grouping, and less on the file reading stuff.  [See the sample here](https://godbolt.org/z/aEdGe88vf)

Comment: I was trying to keep it within an array since that is what we are studying at this point. The vector approach does seem far more elegant. @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the example. Side note: this code snippet is from my test code. Its a bit disorganized and I will be cleaning it up a lot before I submit. Thank you for the advise.

Comment: [Here is a shorter solution using `std::map`](https://godbolt.org/z/55P9T6dEh)

Answer (score 0):

Your Program Seems to have some of the below mentioned issues:

1. Your problem statement states you need to divide it in group of 25 where number are ranging from 0 - 200. You create a function to pass it into an array which is getNumbs but you are using SCORE_SIZE as 26 while reading through the file. This will just read the first 26 characters from your file. Is this according to the problem statement?
2. In function score_count your return type and what you are actually returning does not equate. You either need to provide it an array which would be s_count not s_count[].

Please fix these issues.

Comment: 26 is the number of elements in the file I am pulling from. They represent test scores in a classroom. I will change the array and test again. Thank you for your input.